# prestashop order confirmation page is skipped, it goes to order history

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop version is the latest. Payment modules of First Data and Paypal.

My order when completed via First Data or when there is no payment(using discount voucher to make it zero), it goes directly to Order history bypassing order confirmation page. I have 3 scripts there- Google Analytics, FB Pixel and BizInsights survey and none of them are firing. I see some code changes to the 1.5 version in order confirmation controller, not sure this bugs follows?

Comment: Bump, someone please help

Comment: https://github.com/PrestaShop/firstdata/blob/master/firstdata.php

Comment: It is a bug, this should be a fix https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/419632-paypal-no-order-in-bo-order-history-fix/?p=1981130 but it lets you choose only one currency - didn't test it

Comment: This issue was only resolved by buying a new payment module. Existing First Data and Paypal module kept taking to order history.